# BeautifulSoup4 returns returning html without data in

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

As an example I have code like this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_data(url):
    r = requests.get(url).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r, 'html.parser')
    word = soup.find(class_='mdl-cell mdl-cell--11-col')
    print(word)


get_data('http://savodxon.uz/izoh?sher')
```

I don't know why, but when I print the word there will be nothing

Like this:

```
<h2 class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--11-col" id="definition_l_title"></h2>
```

But should be like this:

```
<h2 id="definition_l_title" class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--11-col">acha</h2>
```

Comment: you may have the most common problem: page may use `JavaScript` to add/update elements but `BeautifulSoup`/`lxml`, `requests`/`urllib` can't run `JS`. You may need [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)  to control real web browser which can run `JS`. OR use (manually) `DevTools` in `Firefox`/`Chrome` (tab `Network`) to see if `JavaScript` reads data from some URL. And try to  use this URL with `requests`. `JS` usually gets `JSON` which can be easy converted to Python dictionary (without `BS`). You can also check if page has (free) `API` for programmers.

Comment: if you turn off`JjavaScript` in web browser and load this page in web browser then you see what you can get with `BeautifulSoup`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have common problem with modern pages: this page uses `JavaScript` to add/update elements but `BeautifulSoup`/`lxml`, `requests`/`urllib` can't run `JavaScript`.

You may need [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)  to control real web browser which can run `JS`. OR use (manually) `DevTools` in `Firefox`/`Chrome` (tab `Network`) to see if `JavaScript` reads data from some URL. And try to  use this URL with `requests`. `JS` usually gets `JSON` which can be easy converted to Python dictionary (without `BS`). You can also check if page has (free) `API` for programmers.

---

Using `DevTools` I found it read data from other URLs (using `post`)

http://savodxon.uz/api/search

http://savodxon.uz/api/get_definition

and they give results as JSON data so it doesn't need `beautifulsoup`

```
import requests

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:98.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/98.0',
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
}

# ---- suggestions ---

url = 'http://savodxon.uz/api/search'

payload = {
    'keyword': 'sher',
    'names': '[object HTMLInputElement]',
}

response = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers)
data = response.json()
#print(data)

# ---

print('--- suggestions ---')
for word in data['suggestions']:
    print('-', word)

# --- definitons ---

url = 'http://savodxon.uz/api/get_definition'

payload = {
    'word': 'sher',
}

response = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers)
data = response.json()
#print(data.keys())

print('--- definitons ---')

for item in data['definition']:
    for meaning in item['meanings']:
        print(meaning['text'])
        for example in meaning['examples']:
            print('-', example['text'], f"({example['takenFrom']})")
```

Result:

```
--- suggestions ---

- sher
- sherboz
- sherdil
- sherik
- sherikchilik
- sheriklashmoq
- sheriklik
- sherlanmoq
- sherobodlik
- sherolgʻin
- sheroz
- sheroza
- sherqadamlik
- shershikorlik
- sherst

--- definitons ---

Mushuksimonlar oilasiga mansub, kalta va sargʻish yungli (erkaklari esa qalin yolli) yirik sutemizuvchi yirtqich hayvon; arslon.
- Ovchining zoʻri sher otadi, Dehqonning zoʻri yer ochadi. (Maqol)
- Oʻzingni er bilsang, oʻzgani sher bil. (Maqol)
- Bular [uch ogʻayni botirlar] tushgan toʻqayning narigi tomonida bir sherning makoni bor edi. (Ertaklar)
Shaxsni sherga nisbatlab ataydi (“azamat“, “botir“ polvon maʼnosida).
- Bu hujjatni butun rayonga tarqatmoqchimiz, sher, obroʻying oshib, choʻqqiga koʻtarilayotganingni bilasanmi? (I. Rahim, Ixlos)
- — Balli, sher, xatni qoʻlingizdan kim oldi? — Bir chol. (A. Qodiriy, Oʻtgan kunlar)
- Yoppa yov-lik otga mining, sherlarim. (Yusuf va Ahmad)
- Figʻon qilgan bunda sherlar, Yoʻlbars, qoplon, bunda erlar (Bahrom va Gulandom)
```

---

BTW:

You may also run it without headers.

Here is example video (without sound) how to use `DevTools`

[How to use DevTools in Firefox to find JSON data in EpicGames.com - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TOQz_W2oELU&list=PLV8_1OSqKPKJ-lHXhjX2-NxtUZcQ29c2E)

Comment: Can I get all the words in data?

Comment: do you means all words which page can display? You would have to search documentation for API to see if it has function for this but I think it doesn't have documentation and it may not have function for it (because page doesn't need it).

Answer (score 2):

The data you see on the page is loaded via JavaScript from external URL so `beautifulsoup` cannot see it. To load the data you can use `requests` module:

```py
import requests

api_url = "https://savodxon.uz/api/get_definition"
data = requests.post(api_url, data={"word": "sher"}).json()
print(data)
```

Prints:

```
{
    "core": "",
    "definition": [
        {
            "meanings": [
                {
                    "examples": [
                        {
                            "takenFrom": "Maqol",
                            "text": "Ovchining zoʻri sher otadi, Dehqonning zoʻri yer ochadi.",
                        },
                        {
                            "takenFrom": "Maqol",
                            "text": "Oʻzingni er bilsang, oʻzgani sher bil.",
                        },
                        {
                            "takenFrom": "Ertaklar",
                            "text": "Bular [uch ogʻayni botirlar] tushgan toʻqayning narigi tomonida bir sherning makoni bor edi.",
                        },
                    ],
                    "reference": "",
                    "tags": "",
                    "text": "Mushuksimonlar oilasiga mansub, kalta va sargʻish yungli (erkaklari esa qalin yolli) yirik sutemizuvchi yirtqich hayvon; arslon.",
                },
                {
                    "examples": [
                        {
                            "takenFrom": "I. Rahim, Ixlos",
                            "text": "Bu hujjatni butun rayonga tarqatmoqchimiz, sher, obroʻying oshib, choʻqqiga koʻtarilayotganingni bilasanmi?",
                        },
                        {
                            "takenFrom": "A. Qodiriy, Oʻtgan kunlar",
                            "text": "— Balli, sher, xatni qoʻlingizdan kim oldi? — Bir chol.",
                        },
                        {
                            "takenFrom": "Yusuf va Ahmad",
                            "text": "Yoppa yov-lik otga mining, sherlarim.",
                        },
                        {
                            "takenFrom": "Bahrom va Gulandom",
                            "text": "Figʻon qilgan bunda sherlar, Yoʻlbars, qoplon, bunda erlar",
                        },
                    ],
                    "reference": "",
                    "tags": "koʻchma",
                    "text": "Shaxsni sherga nisbatlab ataydi (“azamat“, “botir“ polvon maʼnosida).",
                },
            ],
            "phrases": [
                {
                    "meanings": [
                        {
                            "examples": [
                                {
                                    "takenFrom": "Gazetadan",
                                    "text": "Ichkilikning zoʻridan sher boʻlib ketgan Yazturdi endi koʻcha harakati qoidasini unutib qoʻygan edi.",
                                },
                                {
                                    "takenFrom": "H. Tursunqulov, Hayotim qissasi",
                                    "text": "Balli, azamat, bugun jang vaqtida sher boʻlib ketding.",
                                },
                            ],
                            "reference": "",
                            "tags": "ayn.",
                            "text": "Sherlanmoq.",
                        }
                    ],
                    "tags": "",
                    "text": "Sher boʻlmoq",
                }
            ],
            "tags": "",
        }
    ],
    "isDerivative": False,
    "tailStructure": "",
    "type": "ot",
    "wordExists": True,
}
```

---

EDIT: To get words:

```py
import requests

api_url = "https://savodxon.uz/api/search"
d = {"keyword": "sher", "names": "[object HTMLInputElement]"}
data = requests.post(api_url, data=d).json()
print(data)
```

Prints:

```
{
    "success": True,
    "matchFound": True,
    "suggestions": [
        "sher",
        "sherboz",
        "sherdil",
        "sherik",
        "sherikchilik",
        "sheriklashmoq",
        "sheriklik",
        "sherlanmoq",
        "sherobodlik",
        "sherolgʻin",
        "sheroz",
        "sheroza",
        "sherqadamlik",
        "shershikorlik",
        "sherst",
    ],
}
```

Comment: Can I get all the words in data?

Comment: @RyadovoyZadrot See my edit.

Comment: it is a suggestions, but can I get whole list of words.
There are more than 1 million.
Is it possible?